# Migrar página Laravel con datos en BBDD a otra carpeta del servidor

Tags: laravel, linux, servidor, cpanel

Me gustaría saber que hay que tener en cuanta si quiero migrar mi web en Laravel ( que esta actualmente en desarrollo publicada en un servidor)

La cosa es que yo lo tengo publicado en un dominio ( carpeta y) y lo quiero cambiar y subir en otro dominio ( carpeta y)

Esas carpetas estan en diferentes paths, y no sirve con redireccionar a otra carpeta.

Necesitaría coger la carpeta laravel y moverla a otro sitio, mi pregunta es **Cúal es la forma más eficiente y eficaz para no perder ningún dato ni tener conflictos?**

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tus bases de datos ya tienen registros, podrías simplemente mover las carpetas al nuevo dominio y exportar las bases de datos desde el administrador de bases de datos del primer servidor y después importarlas en el nuevo dominio.

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré mañana por la mañana y te dejo la solución, tengo entendido que si no copio la carpeta "vendor" me ahorro mucho espacio, y luego hago un composer install